# Cannot get records from DocumentDB using a Lambdafunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb

I built this lambda function:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

export const handler = async (event: any) => {
  // Connection URI for the DocumentDB cluster
  const uri = 'mongodb://<iusedmyusername>:<iusedmypassword>@docdb-2023-06-08-15-56-01.cluster-cuz2po50vpwx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false';

  try {
    // Create a new MongoClient
    const client = new MongoClient(uri,{
      tlsCAFile: `global-bundle.pem` //Specify the DocDB; cert
    });
    console.log('client',client)

    // Connect to the DocumentDB cluster
    const connection = await client.connect();
    console.log('connection',connection)

    // Select the database and collection to perform the find operation
    const database = client.db('admin');
    console.log('database',database)
    const collection = database.collection('loads');
    console.log('collection',collection)

    // Perform the find operation
    const documents = await collection.find({}).toArray();

    // Log the retrieved documents
    console.log(documents);
    console.log('Hello')
    // Close the connection
    await client.close();

    // Return a successful response
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: 'Documents retrieved successfully',
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occurred during the operation
    console.error('Error:', error);

    // Return an error response
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: 'Error retrieving documents',
    };
  }
};
```

But when I run it, I get this:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "Documents retrieved successfully"
}

last few logs:

2023-06-13T14:55:51.008Z    9dab4142-ca4e-48f7-ac1d-f4abb6c67836    INFO    database Db {
  s: {
    client: MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      mongoLogger: [MongoLogger],
      s: [Object],
      topology: [Topology],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    options: {
      enableUtf8Validation: true,
      forceServerObjectId: false,
      logger: [Logger],
      pkFactory: [Object],
      raw: false,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      retryWrites: false
    },
    logger: Logger { className: 'Db' },
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'secondaryPreferred',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },
    bsonOptions: {
      raw: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      ignoreUndefined: false,
      bsonRegExp: false,
      serializeFunctions: false,
      fieldsAsRaw: {},
      enableUtf8Validation: true
    },
    pkFactory: { createPk: [Function: createPk] },
    readConcern: undefined,
    writeConcern: undefined,
    namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'admin', collection: undefined }
  }
}
2023-06-13T14:55:51.068Z    9dab4142-ca4e-48f7-ac1d-f4abb6c67836    INFO    collection Collection {
  s: {
    db: Db { s: [Object] },
    options: {
      raw: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      ignoreUndefined: false,
      bsonRegExp: false,
      serializeFunctions: false,
      fieldsAsRaw: {},
      enableUtf8Validation: true,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference]
    },
    namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'admin', collection: 'loads' },
    pkFactory: { createPk: [Function: createPk] },
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'secondaryPreferred',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },
    bsonOptions: {
      raw: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      ignoreUndefined: false,
      bsonRegExp: false,
      serializeFunctions: false,
      fieldsAsRaw: {},
      enableUtf8Validation: true
    },
    readConcern: undefined,
    writeConcern: undefined
  }
}
2023-06-13T14:55:51.129Z    9dab4142-ca4e-48f7-ac1d-f4abb6c67836    INFO    []
2023-06-13T14:55:51.129Z    9dab4142-ca4e-48f7-ac1d-f4abb6c67836    INFO    Hello
```

This makes it seem like it is successfully connecting, but the INFO [] indicates that it cannot retrieve any records.

Notes:

1. I have tried a lot of different formats for the URI, this iteration is the most recent.
2. The .pem file is in the same level as the function when I zip it up to upload to lambda.
3. The Lambda and DocDB are in the same VPC, and the inbound rules/security groups should be configured correctly.
4. I am unsure if "admin" is the correct name of my database. As far as I can tell, my cluster and instance do not HAVE names, but I read somewhere that the default is admin.

Edit: After finding the correct database name, now I encounter this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2023-06-13T18:12:18.655Z 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a Task timed out after 3.02 seconds"
}
```

The lambda should not need increased time as there is a very small amount of data in this DocumentDB.

Full log:

```
    2023-06-13T13:12:15.154-05:00   INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:18.v7 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:26e9402591d9c467cdcc7355f843d61968f36ecb6e9ef5ab253cc21163343275

2023-06-13T13:12:15.633-05:00   START RequestId: 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a Version: $LATEST

2023-06-13T13:12:15.914-05:00   2023-06-13T18:12:15.914Z 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a INFO client <ref *1> MongoClient { _events: [Object: null prototype] {}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, mongoLogger: MongoLogger { componentSeverities: { command: 'off', topology: 'off', serverSelection: 'off', connection: 'off', default: 'off' }, maxDocumentLength: 1000, logDestination: Socket { connecting: false, _hadError: false, _parent: null, _host: null, _closeAfterHandlingError: false, _readableState: [ReadableState], _events: [Object: null prototype], _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: undefined, _writableState: [WritableState], allowHalfOpen: false, _sockname: null, _pendingData: null, _pendingEncoding: '', server: null, _server: null, _type: 'pipe', fd: 2, _isStdio: true, destroySoon: [Function: destroy], _destroy: [Function: dummyDestroy], [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 7, [Symbol(kHandle)]: [Pipe], [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0, [Symbol(timeout)]: null, [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null, [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null, [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null, [Symbol(kCapture)]: false, [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false, [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false, [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0, [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0, [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 } }, s: { url: 'mongodb://LambdaPOC1:DocDBTest1@.cluster-cuz2po50vpwx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false', bsonOptions: { raw: false, promoteLongs: true, promoteValues: true, promoteBuffers: false, ignoreUndefined: false, bsonRegExp: false, serializeFunctions: false, fieldsAsRaw: {}, enableUtf8Validation: true }, namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'admin', collection: undefined }, hasBeenClosed: false, sessionPool: ServerSessionPool { client: [Circular *1], sessions: [List] }, activeSessions: Set(0) {}, options: [Getter], readConcern: [Getter], writeConcern: [Getter], readPreference: [Getter], logger: [Getter], isMongoClient: [Getter] }, [Symbol(kCapture)]: false, [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype] { hosts: [ new HostAddress('.cluster-cuz2po50vpwx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017') ], credentials: MongoCredentials { username: 'LambdaPOC1', password: 'DocDBTest1', source: 'admin', mechanism: 'DEFAULT', mechanismProperties: {} }, compressors: [ 'none' ], connectTimeoutMS: 30000, directConnection: false, driverInfo: {}, enableUtf8Validation: true, forceServerObjectId: false, heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000, keepAlive: true, keepAliveInitialDelay: 120000, loadBalanced: false, localThresholdMS: 15, logger: Logger { className: 'MongoClient' }, maxConnecting: 2, maxIdleTimeMS: 0, maxPoolSize: 100, minPoolSize: 0, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500, monitorCommands: false, noDelay: true, pkFactory: { createPk: [Function: createPk] }, raw: false, readPreference: ReadPreference { mode: 'secondaryPreferred', tags: undefined, hedge: undefined, maxStalenessSeconds: undefined, minWireVersion: undefined }, replicaSet: 'rs0', retryReads: true, retryWrites: false, serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000, socketTimeoutMS: 0, srvMaxHosts: 0, srvServiceName: 'mongodb', tls: true, ca: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEEjCCAvqgAwIBAgIJAM2ZN/+nPi27MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGVMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzEmMCQGA1UEAwwdQW1hem9uIFJEUyBhZi1zb3V0aC0xIFJvb3QgQ0Ew\n' + 'HhcNMTkxMDI4MTgwNTU4WhcNMjQxMDI2MTgwNTU4WjCBlTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx\n' + 'EDAOBgNVBAcMB1NlYXR0bGUxEzARBgNVBAgMCldhc2hpbmd0b24xIjAgBgNVBAoM\n' + 'GUFtYXpvbiBXZWIgU2VydmljZXMsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsMCkFtYXpvbiBSRFMx\n' + 'JjAkBgNVBAMMHUFtYXpvbiBSRFMgYWYtc291dGgtMSBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkq\n' + 'hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwR2351uPMZaJk2gMGT+1sk8HE9MQh2rc\n' + '/sCnbxGn2p1c7Oi9aBbd/GiFijeJb2BXvHU+TOq3d3Jjqepq8tapXVt4ojbTJNyC\n' + 'J5E7r7KjTktKdLxtBE1MK25aY+IRJjtdU6vG3KiPKUT1naO3xs3yt0F76WVuFivd\n' + '9OHv2a+KHvPkRUWIxpmAHuMY9SIIMmEZtVE7YZGx5ah0iO4JzItHcbVR0y0PBH55\n' + 'arpFBddpIVHCacp1FUPxSEWkOpI7q0AaU4xfX0fe1BV5HZYRKpBOIp1TtZWvJD+X\n' + 'jGUtL1BEsT5vN5g9MkqdtYrC+3SNpAk4VtpvJrdjraI/hhvfeXNnAwIDAQABo2Mw\n' + 'YTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUEEi/\n' + 'WWMcBJsoGXg+EZwkQ0MscZQwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUEEi/WWMcBJsoGXg+EZwkQ0Ms\n' + 'cZQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAGDZ5js5Pc/gC58LJrwMPXFhJDBS8QuDm23C\n' + 'FFUdlqucskwOS3907ErK1ZkmVJCIqFLArHqskFXMAkRZ2PNR7RjWLqBs+0znG5yH\n' + 'hRKb4DXzhUFQ18UBRcvT6V6zN97HTRsEEaNhM/7k8YLe7P8vfNZ28VIoJIGGgv9D\n' + 'wQBBvkxQ71oOmAG0AwaGD0ORGUfbYry9Dz4a4IcUsZyRWRMADixgrFv6VuETp26s\n' + '/+z+iqNaGWlELBKh3iQCT6Y/1UnkPLO42bxrCSyOvshdkYN58Q2gMTE1SVTqyo8G\n' + 'Lw8lLAz9bnvUSgHzB3jRrSx6ggF/WRMRYlR++y6LXP4SAsSAaC0=\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEEjCCAvqgAwIBAgIJAJYM4LxvTZA6MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGVMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzEmMCQGA1UEAwwdQW1hem9uIFJEUyBldS1zb3V0aC0xIFJvb3QgQ0Ew\n' + 'HhcNMTkxMDMwMjAyMDM2WhcNMjQxMDI4MjAyMDM2WjCBlTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx\n' + 'EDAOBgNVBAcMB1NlYXR0bGUxEzARBgNVBAgMCldhc2hpbmd0b24xIjAgBgNVBAoM\n' + 'GUFtYXpvbiBXZWIgU2VydmljZXMsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsMCkFtYXpvbiBSRFMx\n' + 'JjAkBgNVBAMMHUFtYXpvbiBSRFMgZXUtc291dGgtMSBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkq\n' + 'hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqM921jXCXeqpRNCS9CBPOe5N7gMaEt+D\n' + 's5uR3riZbqzRlHGiF1jZihkXfHAIQewDwy+Yz+Oec1aEZCQMhUHxZJPusuX0cJfj\n' + 'b+UluFqHIijL2TfXJ3D0PVLLoNTQJZ8+GAPECyojAaNuoHbdVqxhOcznMsXIXVFq\n' + 'yVLKDGvyKkJjai/iSPDrQMXufg3kWt0ISjNLvsG5IFXgP4gttsM8i0yvRd4QcHoo\n' + 'DjvH7V3cS+CQqW5SnDrGnHToB0RLskE1ET+oNOfeN9PWOxQprMOX/zmJhnJQlTqD\n' + 'QP7jcf7SddxrKFjuziFiouskJJyNDsMjt1Lf60+oHZhed2ogTeifGwIDAQABo2Mw\n' + 'YTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUFBAF\n' + 'cgJe/BBuZiGeZ8STfpkgRYQwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUFBAFcgJe/BBuZiGeZ8STfpkg\n' + 'RYQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAKAYUtlvDuX2UpZW9i1QgsjFuy/ErbW0dLHU\n' + 'e/IcFtju2z6RLZ+uF+5A8Kme7IKG1hgt8s+w9TRVQS/7ukQzoK3TaN6XKXRosjtc\n' + 'o9Rm4gYWM8bmglzY1TPNaiI4HC7546hSwJhubjN0bXCuj/0sHD6w2DkiGuwKNAef\n' + 'yTu5vZhPkeNyXLykxkzz7bNp2/PtMBnzIp+WpS7uUDmWyScGPohKMq5PqvL59z+L\n' + 'ZI3CYeMZrJ5VpXUg3fNNIz/83N3G0sk7wr0ohs/kHTP7xPOYB0zD7Ku4HA0Q9Swf\n' + 'WX0qr6UQgTPMjfYDLffI7aEId0gxKw1eGYc6Cq5JAZ3ipi/cBFc=\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEEjCCAvqgAwIBAgIJANew34ehz5l8MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGVMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzEmMCQGA1UEAwwdQW1hem9uIFJEUyBtZS1zb3V0aC0xIFJvb3QgQ0Ew\n' + 'HhcNMTkwNTEwMjE0ODI3WhcNMjQwNTA4MjE0ODI3WjCBlTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx\n' + 'EDAOBgNVBAcMB1NlYXR0bGUxEzARBgNVBAgMCldhc2hpbmd0b24xIjAgBgNVBAoM\n' + 'GUFtYXpvbiBXZWIgU2VydmljZXMsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsMCkFtYXpvbiBSRFMx\n' + 'JjAkBgNVBAMMHUFtYXpvbiBSRFMgbWUtc291dGgtMSBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkq\n' + 'hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAp7BYV88MukcY+rq0r79+C8UzkT30fEfT\n' + 'aPXbx1d6M7uheGN4FMaoYmL+JE1NZPaMRIPTHhFtLSdPccInvenRDIatcXX+jgOk\n' + 'UA6lnHQ98pwN0pfDUyz/Vph4jBR9LcVkBbe0zdoKKp+HGbMPRU0N2yNrog9gM5O8\n' + 'gkU/3O2csJ/OFQNnj4c2NQloGMUpEmedwJMOyQQfcUyt9CvZDfIPNnheUS29jGSw\n' + 'ERpJe/AENu8Pxyc72jaXQuD+FEi2Ck6lBkSlWYQFhTottAeGvVFNCzKszCntrtqd\n' + 'rdYUwurYsLTXDHv9nW2hfDUQa0mhXf9gNDOBIVAZugR9NqNRNyYLHQIDAQABo2Mw\n' + 'YTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU54cf\n' + 'DjgwBx4ycBH8+/r8WXdaiqYwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAU54cfDjgwBx4ycBH8+/r8WXda\n' + 'iqYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAIIMTSPx/dR7jlcxggr+O6OyY49Rlap2laKA\n' + 'eC/XI4ySP3vQkIFlP822U9Kh8a9s46eR0uiwV4AGLabcu0iKYfXjPkIprVCqeXV7\n' + 'ny9oDtrbflyj7NcGdZLvuzSwgl9SYTJp7PVCZtZutsPYlbJrBPHwFABvAkMvRtDB\n' + 'hitIg4AESDGPoCl94sYHpfDfjpUDMSrAMDUyO6DyBdZH5ryRMAs3lGtsmkkNUrso\n' + 'aTW6R05681Z0mvkRdb+cdXtKOSuDZPoe2wJJIaz3IlNQNSrB5TImMYgmt6iAsFhv\n' + '3vfTSTKrZDNTJn4ybG6pq1zWExoXsktZPylJly6R3RBwV6nwqBM=\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEBjCCAu6gAwIBAgIJAMc0ZzaSUK51MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGPMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzEgMB4GA1UEAwwXQW1hem9uIFJEUyBSb290IDIwMTkgQ0EwHhcNMTkw\n' + 'ODIyMTcwODUwWhcNMjQwODIyMTcwODUwWjCBjzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEDAOBgNV\n' + 'BAcMB1NlYXR0bGUxEzARBgNVBAgMCldhc2hpbmd0b24xIjAgBgNVBAoMGUFtYXpv\n' + 'biBXZWIgU2VydmljZXMsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsMCkFtYXpvbiBSRFMxIDAeBgNV\n' + 'BAMMF0FtYXpvbiBSRFMgUm9vdCAyMDE5IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOC\n' + 'AQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArXnF/E6/Qh+ku3hQTSKPMhQQlCpoWvnIthzX6MK3p5a0eXKZ\n' + 'oWIjYcNNG6UwJjp4fUXl6glp53Jobn+tWNX88dNH2n8DVbppSwScVE2LpuL+94vY\n' + '0EYE/XxN7svKea8YvlrqkUBKyxLxTjh+U/KrGOaHxz9v0l6ZNlDbuaZw3qIWdD/I\n' + '6aNbGeRUVtpM6P+bWIoxVl/caQylQS6CEYUk+CpVyJSkopwJlzXT07tMoDL5WgX9\n' + 'O08KVgDNz9qP/IGtAcRduRcNioH3E9v981QO1zt/Gpb2f8NqAjUUCUZzOnij6mx9\n' + 'McZ+9cWX88CRzR0vQODWuZscgI08NvM69Fn2SQIDAQABo2MwYTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E\n' + 'BAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUc19g2LzLA5j0Kxc0LjZa\n' + 'pmD/vB8wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUc19g2LzLA5j0Kxc0LjZapmD/vB8wDQYJKoZIhvcN\n' + 'AQELBQADggEBAHAG7WTmyjzPRIM85rVj+fWHsLIvqpw6DObIjMWokpliCeMINZFV\n' + 'ynfgBKsf1ExwbvJNzYFXW6dihnguDG9VMPpi2up/ctQTN8tm9nDKOy08uNZoofMc\n' + 'NUZxKCEkVKZv+IL4oHoeayt8egtv3ujJM6V14AstMQ6SwvwvA93EP/Ug2e4WAXHu\n' + 'cbI1NAbUgVDqp+DRdfvZkgYKryjTWd/0+1fS8X1bBZVWzl7eirNVnHbSH2ZDpNuY\n' + '0SBd8dj5F6ld3t58ydZbrTHze7JJOd8ijySAp4/kiu9UfZWuTPABzDa/DSdz9Dk/\n' + 'zPW4CXXvhLmE02TA9/HeCw3KEHIwicNuEfw=\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEEDCCAvigAwIBAgIJAKFMXyltvuRdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGUMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzElMCMGA1UEAwwcQW1hem9uIFJEUyBCZXRhIFJvb3QgMjAxOSBDQTAe\n' + 'Fw0xOTA4MTkxNzM4MjZaFw0yNDA4MTkxNzM4MjZaMIGUMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEQ\n' + 'MA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEiMCAGA1UECgwZ\n' + 'QW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1hem9uIFJEUzEl\n' + 'MCMGA1UEAwwcQW1hem9uIFJEUyBCZXRhIFJvb3QgMjAxOSBDQTCCASIwDQYJKoZI\n' + 'hvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMkZdnIH9ndatGAcFo+DppGJ1HUt4x+zeO+0\n' + 'ZZ29m0sfGetVulmTlv2d5b66e+QXZFWpcPQMouSxxYTW08TbrQiZngKr40JNXftA\n' + 'atvzBqIImD4II0ZX5UEVj2h98qe/ypW5xaDN7fEa5e8FkYB1TEemPaWIbNXqchcL\n' + 'tV7IJPr3Cd7Z5gZJlmujIVDPpMuSiNaal9/6nT9oqN+JSM1fx5SzrU5ssg1Vp1vv\n' + '5Xab64uOg7wCJRB9R2GC9XD04odX6VcxUAGrZo6LR64ZSifupo3l+R5sVOc5i8NH\n' + 'skdboTzU9H7+oSdqoAyhIU717PcqeDum23DYlPE2nGBWckE+eT8CAwEAAaNjMGEw\n' + 'DgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFK2hDBWl\n' + 'sbHzt/EHd0QYOooqcFPhMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFK2hDBWlsbHzt/EHd0QYOooqcFPh\n' + 'MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAO/718k8EnOqJDx6wweUscGTGL/QdKXUzTVRAx\n' + 'JUsjNUv49mH2HQVEW7oxszfH6cPCaupNAddMhQc4C/af6GHX8HnqfPDk27/yBQI+\n' + 'yBBvIanGgxv9c9wBbmcIaCEWJcsLp3HzXSYHmjiqkViXwCpYfkoV3Ns2m8bp+KCO\n' + 'y9XmcCKRaXkt237qmoxoh2sGmBHk2UlQtOsMC0aUQ4d7teAJG0q6pbyZEiPyKZY1\n' + 'XR/UVxMJL0Q4iVpcRS1kaNCMfqS2smbLJeNdsan8pkw1dvPhcaVTb7CvjhJtjztF\n' + 'YfDzAI5794qMlWxwilKMmUvDlPPOTen8NNHkLwWvyFCH7Doh\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEFjCCAv6gAwIBAgIJAMzYZJ+R9NBVMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGXMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzEoMCYGA1UEAwwfQW1hem9uIFJEUyBQcmV2aWV3IFJvb3QgMjAxOSBD\n' + 'QTAeFw0xOTA4MjEyMjI5NDlaFw0yNDA4MjEyMjI5NDlaMIGXMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV\n' + 'UzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEiMCAGA1UE\n' + 'CgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1hem9uIFJE\n' + 'UzEoMCYGA1UEAwwfQW1hem9uIFJEUyBQcmV2aWV3IFJvb3QgMjAxOSBDQTCCASIw\n' + 'DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAM7kkS6vjgKKQTPynC2NjdN5aPPV\n' + 'O71G0JJS/2ARVBVJd93JLiGovVJilfWYfwZCs4gTRSSjrUD4D4HyqCd6A+eEEtJq\n' + 'M0DEC7i0dC+9WNTsPszuB206Jy2IUmxZMIKJAA1NHSbIMjB+b6/JhbSUi7nKdbR/\n' + 'brj83bF+RoSA+ogrgX7mQbxhmFcoZN9OGaJgYKsKWUt5Wqv627KkGodUK8mDepgD\n' + 'S3ZfoRQRx3iceETpcmHJvaIge6+vyDX3d9Z22jmvQ4AKv3py2CmU2UwuhOltFDwB\n' + '0ddtb39vgwrJxaGfiMRHpEP1DfNLWHAnA69/pgZPwIggidS+iBPUhgucMp8CAwEA\n' + 'AaNjMGEwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYE\n' + 'FGnTGpQuQ2H/DZlXMQijZEhjs7TdMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFGnTGpQuQ2H/DZlXMQij\n' + 'ZEhjs7TdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQC3xz1vQvcXAfpcZlngiRWeqU8zQAMQ\n' + 'LZPCFNv7PVk4pmqX+ZiIRo4f9Zy7TrOVcboCnqmP/b/mNq0gVF4O+88jwXJZD+f8\n' + '/RnABMZcnGU+vK0YmxsAtYU6TIb1uhRFmbF8K80HHbj9vSjBGIQdPCbvmR2zY6VJ\n' + 'BYM+w9U9hp6H4DVMLKXPc1bFlKA5OBTgUtgkDibWJKFOEPW3UOYwp9uq6pFoN0AO\n' + 'xMTldqWFsOF3bJIlvOY0c/1EFZXu3Ns6/oCP//Ap9vumldYMUZWmbK+gK33FPOXV\n' + '8BQ6jNC29icv7lLDpRPwjibJBXX+peDR5UK4FdYcswWEB1Tix5X8dYu6\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIECTCCAvGgAwIBAgICEAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgZUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT\n' + 'MRAwDgYDVQQHDAdTZWF0dGxlMRMwEQYDVQQIDApXYXNoaW5ndG9uMSIwIAYDVQQK\n' + 'DBlBbWF6b24gV2ViIFNlcnZpY2VzLCBJbmMuMRMwEQYDVQQLDApBbWF6b24gUkRT\n' + 'MSYwJAYDVQQDDB1BbWF6b24gUkRTIGFmLXNvdXRoLTEgUm9vdCBDQTAeFw0xOTEw\n' + 'MjgxODA2NTNaFw0yNDEwMjgxODA2NTNaMIGQMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UE\n' + 'CAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTEiMCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9u\n' + 'IFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1hem9uIFJEUzEhMB8GA1UE\n' + 'AwwYQW1hem9uIFJEUyBhZi1zb3V0aC0xIENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOC\n' + 'AQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvtV1OqmFa8zCVQSKOvPUJERLVFtd4rZmDpImc5rIoeBk7w/P\n' + '9lcKUJjO8R/w1a2lJXx3oQ81tiY0Piw6TpT62YWVRMWrOw8+Vxq1dNaDSFp9I8d0\n' + 'UHillSSbOk6FOrPDp+R6AwbGFqUDebbN5LFFoDKbhNmH1BVS0a6YNKpGigLRqhka\n' + 'cClPslWtPqtjbaP3Jbxl26zWzLo7OtZl98dR225pq8aApNBwmtgA7Gh60HK/cX0t\n' + '32W94n8D+GKSg6R4MKredVFqRTi9hCCNUu0sxYPoELuM+mHiqB5NPjtm92EzCWs+\n' + '+vgWhMc6GxG+82QSWx1Vj8sgLqtE/vLrWddf5QIDAQABo2YwZDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E\n' + 'BAMCAQYwEgYDVR0TAQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUuLB4gYVJrSKJj/Gz\n' + 'pqc6yeA+RcAwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUEEi/WWMcBJsoGXg+EZwkQ0MscZQwDQYJKoZI\n' + 'hvcNAQELBQADggEBABauYOZxUhe9/RhzGJ8MsWCz8eKcyDVd4FCnY6Qh+9wcmYNT\n' + 'LtnD88LACtJKb/b81qYzcB0Em6+zVJ3Z9jznfr6buItE6es9wAo'... 164184 more characters, waitQueueTimeoutMS: 0, zlibCompressionLevel: 0, dbName: 'test', userSpecifiedAuthSource: false, userSpecifiedReplicaSet: true, mongoLoggerOptions: { componentSeverities: [Object], maxDocumentLength: 1000, logDestination: [Socket] }, metadata: { driver: [Object], platform: 'Node.js v18.16.0, LE', os: [Object], env: [Object] }, [Symbol(@@mdb.enableMongoLogger)]: false } }

2023-06-13T13:12:18.657-05:00   2023-06-13T18:12:18.655Z 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a Task timed out after 3.02 seconds

2023-06-13T13:12:18.657-05:00   END RequestId: 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a

2023-06-13T13:12:18.657-05:00   REPORT RequestId: 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a Duration: 3022.30 ms Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 93 MB Init Duration: 466.62 ms

2023-06-13T13:12:18.749-05:00   INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:18.v7 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:26e9402591d9c467cdcc7355f843d61968f36ecb6e9ef5ab253cc21163343275
```

Comment: @jarmod gotcha - should be fixed now.

Comment: I suspect that `admin` is not the name of the database that you should be connecting to. That database is used for authenticating and authorizing MongoDB users. You should find out what the correct DB name is, either from the administrator of this DB or by connecting and querying the configured list of DBs.

Comment: Thanks! Got the correct name 'test' and now I am encountering a timeout error (logs added)

Comment: @jarmod The lambda and documentDB are in the same VPC and security group, and there is definitely not enough data to warrant a timeout.

Comment: I think you are saying that the Lambda function and DocumentDB instance have the same security group. That's not typically how you would set it up (you'd have different SGs) but it should work as long as the SG allows inbound traffic from itself. That doesn't happen automatically. You have to add an ingress rule from the SG [to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565372/self-referencing-aws-security-groups) on the relevant port.

Comment: @jarmod gotcha - I do have an inbound rule for the security group with the custom source being itself on the same port